# The color will not change on a div, generated by a script

Tags: javascript, css

```
  var BGLinks = (function() {
  var that = {};

  // can be set like BGLinks.parameter
  that.version = 'NIV';
  that.clickTooltip = false;
  that.apocrypha = false;
  that.showTooltips = true;
  that.host = 'www.biblegateway.com';

  var showTimer = 0;
  var hideTimer = 0;
  var container;
  var addedCSS = false;
  var setupRun = false;
  var delay = 1000;
  var bgHost;
  var toolsHost;
  var cdHost;
  var browser = navigator.appVersion;
  var book_string = 'Genesis|Gen?|Gn|Exodus|Exod?|Ex|Leviticus|Le?v|Numbers|Nu?m|Nu|Deuteronomy|Deut?|Dt|Josh?ua|Josh?|Jsh|Judges|Ju?dg|Jg|Ru(?:th)?|Ru?t|(?:1|i|2|ii) ?Samuel|(?:1|i|2|ii) ?S(?:a|m)|(?:1|i|2|ii) ?Sam|(?:1|i|2|ii) ?Kin(?:gs?)?|(?:1|i|2|ii) ?Kgs|(?:1|i|2|ii) ?Chronicles|(?:1|i|2|ii) ?Chr(?:o?n)?|(?:1|i|2|ii) ?Cr|Ezra?|Nehemiah|Neh?|Esther|Esth?|Jo?b|Psalms?|Psa?|Proverbs|Pro?v?|Ecclesiastes|Ec(?:cl?)?|Song (?:O|o)f Solomon|Song (?:O|o)f Songs?|Son(?:gs?)?|SS|Isaiah?|Isa?|Jeremiah|Je?r|Lamentations|La(?:me?)?|Ezekiel|Eze?k?|Daniel|Da?n|Da|Hosea|Hos?|Hs|Jo(?:el?)?|Am(?:os?)?|Obadiah|Ob(?:ad?)?|Jon(?:ah?)?|Jnh|Mic(?:ah?)?|Mi|Nah?um|Nah?|Habakkuk|Hab|Zephaniah|Ze?ph?|Haggai|Hagg?|Hg|Zechariah|Ze?ch?|Malachi|Ma?l|Matthew|Matt?|Mt|Mark|Ma(?:r|k)|M(?:r|k)|Luke?|Lk|Lu?c|John|Jn|Ac(?:ts?)?|Romans|Ro?m|(?:1|i|2|ii) ?Corinthians|(?:1|i|2|ii) ?C(?:or?)?|Galatians|Gal?|Gl|Ephesians|Eph?|Philippians|Phil|Colossians|Co?l|(?:1|i|2|ii) ?Thessalonians|(?:1|i|2|ii) ?Th(?:e(?:ss?)?)?|(?:1|i|2|ii) ?Timothy|(?:1|i|2|ii) ?Tim|(?:1|i|2|ii) ?T(?:i|m)|Ti(?:tus)?|Ti?t|Philemon|Phl?m|Hebrews|Heb?|Jam(?:es)?|Jms|Jas|(?:1|i|2|ii) ?Peter|(?:1|i|2|ii) ?Pe?t?|(?:1|i|2|ii|3|iii) ?J(?:oh)?n?|Jude?|Revelations?|Rev|R(?:e|v)';

  var apoc_books = '|Tobit?|To?b|Judi(?:th?)?|Jdt|(?:1|2) ?Mac(?:cabees)?|(?:1|2) ?Ma?|Wi(?:sdom)?|Wi?s|Sir(?:ach)?|Ba(?:ruc?h)?|Ba?r';

  that.linkVerses = function() {
    updateURLs();
    insertBiblerefs(document.body);
    if (that.showTooltips === true) {
      addBiblerefListeners();
    }
    setup();
  }

  var updateURLs = function() {
    bgHost = window.location.protocol + '//' + that.host;
    toolsHost = bgHost + '/share/tooltips/data';
    cdHost = bgHost + '/public/link-to-us/tooltips';
  }

  var insertBiblerefs = function(node) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
      var new_nodes = searchNode(node,0);
      return new_nodes;
    }
    else if (node.tagName != undefined && node.tagName.match(/^(?:a|h\d|img|pre|input|option)$/i)) {
      return null;
    }
    else {
      var children = node.childNodes;
      var i = 0;
      while(i<children.length) {
        var new_nodes = insertBiblerefs(children[i]);
        i += new_nodes +1;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  var searchNode = function(node, inserted_nodes) {
    var apoc_string = that.apocrypha === true ? apoc_books : '';
    //finds book and chapter for each verse that been separated by &,and,etc...
    var book_chap = '((?:('+book_string+apoc_string+')(?:\.)? ?)?(?:(\\d*):)?(\\d+(?:(?:ff|f|\\w)|(?:\\s?(?:-|â€“|â€”)\\s?\\d+)?)))([^a-z0-9]*)';
    var regex_string = '(?:'+book_string+apoc_string+')(?:\.)? ?\\d+:\\d+(?:ff|f|\\w)?(?:\\s?(?:(?:(?:-|â€“|â€”)\\s?(?:(?:'+book_string+apoc_string+')(?:\.)?\\s)?)|(?:(?:,|;|&amp;|&|and|cf\\.|cf)))\\s?(?:(?:(?:vv.|vs.|vss.|v.) ?)?\\d+\\w?)(?::\\d+\\w?)?)*';
    var regex = new RegExp(regex_string,'i');
    var verse_match = node.nodeValue.match(regex);
    if (verse_match == null) {
      return inserted_nodes;
    } else {
      var text = node.nodeValue;
      var before_text = text.substr(0,text.indexOf(verse_match[0]));
      var after_text = text.substr(text.indexOf(verse_match[0])+verse_match[0].length);
      if (before_text.length > 0) {
        var newTxtNode = document.createTextNode(before_text);
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(newTxtNode, node);
        inserted_nodes++;
      }

      var book_chap_regex = new RegExp(book_chap, 'gi');
      var book;
      var chapter;
      var verse;

      while (matched = book_chap_regex.exec(verse_match[0])) {
        // break up what may be multiple references into links.
        if (matched[2] != '' && matched[2] != null) {
          book = matched[2];
        }
        if (matched[3] != '' && matched[3] != null) {
          chapter = matched[3];
        }
        verse = matched[4];
        var newLinkNode = document.createElement("a");
        newLinkNode.className = 'bibleref';
        newLinkNode.target = '_BLANK';
        var passage = book+' '+chapter+':'+verse;
        newLinkNode.href = bgHost+'/passage/?search='+passage+'&version='+that.version+'&src=tools';
        newLinkNode.innerHTML = matched[1];
        if (that.clickTooltip === true) {
          newLinkNode.onclick=function() {return false};
        }
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(newLinkNode, node);
        inserted_nodes++;
        if (matched[6] != '') {
          var newTxtNode = document.createTextNode(matched[5]);
          node.parentNode.insertBefore(newTxtNode, node);
          // do we need to update inserted_nodes with this?
        }
      }

      if (after_text.length > 0) {
        var newTxtNode = document.createTextNode(after_text);
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(newTxtNode, node);
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
        inserted_nodes = searchNode(newTxtNode,inserted_nodes+1);
      }
      else { 
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
      }
    }
    return inserted_nodes;
  }

  var addCSS = function() {
    if (!addedCSS) {
      var css = document.createElement('link');
      css.type = "text/css";
      css.rel = "stylesheet";
      if (browser.search('MSIE 6.0') != -1) {
        browser = 'ie6';
        css.href = cdHost+'/theme/bglinks-ie.css';
      } else {
        css.href = cdHost+'/theme/popover.css';
      }
      css.media = "screen";
      var n1 = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].childNodes[0] 
      n1.parentNode.insertBefore(css,n1);
      addedCSS = true;
    }
  }

  var addBiblerefListeners = function() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for ( var i = 0;i< links.length;i++) {
      var link = links[i]
      if (link.className && link.className == 'bibleref') {
        if (that.clickTooltip !== true) {
          addListener(link,'mouseover', linkMouseover);  
          addListener(link,'mouseout',  linkMouseout);
        } else {
          addListener(link,'click', toggleTooltip);  
        }
      }
    }
  }

  var addListener = function (listen_object, action, callback) {
    if (listen_object.addEventListener) {
      if (action == 'mouseover') {
        listen_object.addEventListener("mouseover",callback,false);
      } else if (action == 'mouseout') {
        listen_object.addEventListener("mouseout",callback,false);
      } else if (action == 'click') {
        listen_object.addEventListener("click",callback,false);
      }
    } else if (listen_object.attachEvent) {
      if (action == 'mouseover') {
        listen_object.attachEvent("onmouseover",callback);
      } else if (action == 'mouseout') {
        listen_object.attachEvent("onmouseout",callback);
      } else if (action == 'click') {
        listen_object.attachEvent("onclick",callback);
      }
    } else {
      if (action == 'mouseover') {
        listen_object.onmouseover = callback;
      } else if (action == 'mouseout'){
        listen_object.onmouseout = callback;
      } else if (action == 'click') {
        listen_object.onclick = callback;
      }
    } 
  }

  var toggleTooltip = function(e) {
    if (!e) {
      e = window.event;
    }

    link = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var reference;
    var bibleref;
    if (bibleref = link.getAttribute('data-bibleref')) {
      reference = bibleref;
    } else {
      reference = link.href.match(/search=(.*?)(?:&.*)?$/)[1];
    }

    var id = reference.replace(/%20| /g, '');
    var id = reference.replace(/:/g, '_');
    var tooltip = document.getElementById('bg_popup-'+id);
    if (tooltip === null || tooltip.style.display == 'none') {
      showTooltip(e);
    } else {
      hideTooltip(e);
    }
  }

  var showTooltip = function(e) {
    if (!e) {
      e = window.event;
    }
    link = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var reference;
    var bibleref;
    if (bibleref = link.getAttribute('data-bibleref')) {
      reference = bibleref;
    } else {
      reference = link.href.match(/search=(.*?)(?:&.*)?$/)[1];
    }

    var id = reference.replace(/%20| /g, '');
    id = id.replace(/:/g, '_');
    id = id.replace(/ /g, '');
    var tooltip = document.getElementById('bg_popup-'+id);
    hideAllTooltips(e);
    if (tooltip === null) {
      tooltip = getTooltip(reference, link);
    } else {
      tooltip_loc = tooltipLocation(link);
      tooltip.style.left = tooltip_loc.offsetX+'px';
      tooltip.style.top = tooltip_loc.offsetY+'px';
      tooltip.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }

  var hideTooltip = function(e) {
    if (!e) {
      e = window.event;
    }
    target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var reference;
    var bibleref;
    if (bibleref = link.getAttribute('data-bibleref')) {
      reference = bibleref;
    } else {
      reference = link.href.match(/search=(.*?)(?:&.*)?$/)[1];
    }

    reference = reference.replace(/%20| /g, '');
    reference = reference.replace(/:/g, '_');

    var tooltip = document.getElementById('bg_popup-'+reference);
    if (tooltip) {
      tooltip.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  var hideAllTooltips = function(e) {
    var divs = container.children;
    for (var i = 0;i < divs.length;i++) {
      divs[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  var linkMouseover = function(e) {
    if (!e) {
      e = window.event;
    }
    if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a') {
      window.clearTimeout(showTimer);
      showTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {showTooltip(e)}, delay);
    }
  }

  var linkMouseout = function(e) {
    if (!e) {
      e = window.event;
    }
    if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a' && showTimer) {
      window.clearTimeout(showTimer);
      window.clearTimeout(hideTimer);
      hideTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {hideTooltip(e)}, delay);
    }
  }

  var tooltipMouseover = function(e) {
    if (!e) {
      e = window.event;
    }
    var relNode = e.relatedTarget || e.fromElement;
    while (relNode && relNode != null && (!relNode.className || relNode.className.indexOf('bg_popup-outer') == -1) && relNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'body') {
      relNode = relNode.parentNode;
    }
    if (relNode && relNode.className && relNode.className.indexOf('bg_popup-outer') != -1) return;
    window.clearTimeout(showTimer);
    window.clearTimeout(hideTimer);
  }

  var tooltipMouseout = function(e) {
    if (!e) {
      e = window.event;
    }
    var relNode = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
    while (relNode && relNode != null && (!relNode.className || relNode.className.indexOf('bg_popup-outer') == -1) && relNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'body') {
      relNode = relNode.parentNode;
    }
    if (relNode && relNode.className && relNode.className.indexOf('bg_popup-outer') != -1) return;
    window.clearTimeout(hideTimer);
    hideTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {hideAllTooltips(e)}, delay);
  }

  var createContainer = function() { 
    container = document.createElement('div');
    container.id = 'bg_popup-container';
    document.body.appendChild(container);
  }

  var getTooltip = function(reference, link) {
    var tooltip = document.createElement('div');
    tooltip.style.display='none';
    tooltip.className = 'bg_popup bg_popup-outer';
    var tooltip_loc = tooltipLocation(link);
    tooltip.style.top = tooltip_loc.offsetY+'px';
    tooltip.style.left = tooltip_loc.offsetX+'px';
    var id = 'bg_popup-'+reference.replace(/%20/g, '');
    id = id.replace(/:/g, '_');
    id = id.replace(/ /g, '');
    tooltip.id=id;
    tooltip.innerHTML = '<div class="bg_popup-header"><div class="bg_popup-header_title"><strong>'+reference.replace(/%20/g, ' ')+'</strong></div></div><div class="bg_popup-content"><div class="bg_popup-spinner"><img alt="loading" src="'+cdHost+'/theme/images/tools/spinner.gif"/></div></div><div class="bg_popup-footer"><a class="bg_popup-bglogo" href="'+bgHost+'/" target="_blank"></a></div>';
    tooltip.style.display = 'block';
    addCloseButton(tooltip);

    tooltip = container.appendChild(tooltip);
    if (that.clickTooltip !== true) {
      addListener(tooltip,'mouseover', tooltipMouseover);
      addListener(tooltip,'mouseout', tooltipMouseout);
    }

    var remote_passage = document.createElement('script');
    remote_passage.type = 'text/javascript';
    remote_passage.src = toolsHost+'/?search='+reference+'&version='+that.version+'&callback=BGLinks.updateTooltip';
    remote_passage.id = 'bg_remote_passage_script-'+reference.replace(/%20/g, '');
    remote_passage.id = remote_passage.id.replace(/:/g, '_');
    remote_passage.id = remote_passage.id.replace(/ /g, '');
    var hook = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    hook.parentNode.insertBefore(remote_passage, hook);

    return tooltip;
  }

  that.updateTooltip = function(tooltip_content) {
    var id = 'bg_popup-'+tooltip_content.reference.replace(/%20/g, '');
    id = 'bg_popup-'+tooltip_content.reference.replace(/:/g, '_');
    id = id.replace(/ /g, '');
    var tooltip = document.getElementById(id);

    var reference_display = tooltip_content.reference_display.replace(/%20/g,' ');
    if (tooltip_content.text == undefined) {
      if (tooltip.text == undefined) {
        tooltip_content.text = 'Retrieving Passage...'
      }
      else {
        tooltip_content.text = tooltip.text;
        reference_display = tooltip.reference_display;
      }
    }

    tooltip.innerHTML = '<div class="bg_popup-header"><div class="bg_popup-header_title"><strong>'+reference_display+' '+tooltip_content.version+'</strong></div></div><div class="bg_popup-content"><div class="bg_popup-content-bible"><p>'+tooltip_content.text+' <a class="bg_popup-copyright" href="'+bgHost+tooltip_content.version_url+'" target="_blank">('+tooltip_content.version+')</a> <a class="bg_popup-more" href="'+bgHost+'/passage/?search='+tooltip_content.reference+'&version='+tooltip_content.version+'&src=tools" target="_blank">More</a></p></div></div><div class="bg_popup-footer"><a class="bg_popup-bglogo" href="'+bgHost+'/" target="_blank"></a></div>';
    addCloseButton(tooltip);
  }

  var addCloseButton = function(tooltip) {
    var divs = tooltip.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length;i++) {
      if (divs[i].className == 'bg_popup-header_right') {
        addListener(divs[i], 'click', hideAllTooltips);
      }
    }
  }

  var tooltipLocation = function(link) {
    var tooltip_height = 234;
    var tooltip_width = 362;

    if (typeof(window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
      width = window.innerWidth;
      height = window.innerHeight;
    } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
      width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
      height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
      width = document.body.clientWidth;
      height = document.body.clientHeight;
    } 

    var display_loc = {};

    var offsetPos = getOffsetPos(link);
    var leftPos = offsetPos.leftPos;
    var topPos = offsetPos.topPos;

    if (link.offsetWidth/link.parentNode.offsetWidth >.5) {
      leftPos = getOffsetPos(link.parentNode);
      leftPos = leftPos.leftPos;
    }
    if ((leftPos + tooltip_width+5) > width) {
      leftPos -= tooltip_width;
      if ((leftPos + tooltip_width + link.offsetWidth) <= width) leftPos += link.offsetWidth;
      if (leftPos + tooltip_width + 25 <= width) leftPos += 25;
      if (leftPos - (link.offsetWidth/2) >= 0) leftPos -= (link.offsetWidth/2);
    } else {
      if (leftPos + (link.offsetWidth/2) <= width && link.offsetWidth/link.parentNode.offsetWidth <=.5) leftPos += (link.offsetWidth/2);
      if (leftPos - 35 >= 0) {
        leftPos -= 35;
      }
    }

    var scrollY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || 0;;
    if ((topPos+link.offsetHeight+tooltip_height+15) <= height +scrollY || topPos-tooltip_height+5 <0) {
      topPos += link.offsetHeight + 10;  
    } else {
      topPos -= tooltip_height + 10;
    }

    display_loc.offsetY = topPos;
    display_loc.offsetX = leftPos;

    return (display_loc);
  }

  var getOffsetPos = function(linkObj) {
    var topPos = leftPos = 0;
    do {
      topPos += linkObj.offsetTop;
      leftPos += linkObj.offsetLeft;
      if(document.all) {
        topPos+=linkObj.clientTop;
        leftPos+=linkObj.clientLeft;
      }
      } while ((linkObj = linkObj.offsetParent) != null);
    return {'topPos' : topPos, 'leftPos' : leftPos};
  }

  var setup = function() {
    if (!setupRun) {
      if (that.showTooltips === true) {
        addCSS();
        addListener(document, 'click', hideAllTooltips);
      }
      createContainer();
      setupRun = true;
    }
  }

  return that;
})();

$(document).ready(function() {
    BGLinks.linkVerses();
});
```

This is the script, located at http://churchofcwa.wikia.com/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.js/bglinks.js, that I am encountering an error with css, this script was copied from https://www.biblegateway.com/public/link-to-us/tooltips/bglinks.js and is not made by me. The issue I am encountering is via the css page (MediaWiki:Common.css) when changing the color of the script by

```
.bg_popup-content-bible {color:#000000}
```

The font color of the p tag within that div does not change. Originally I had it set to the p tag specifically of that div, but a css checker said that styling would be overqualified, and it was not functional nevertheless. What the script does is take all Bible verses listed on a page, and automatically links them to Biblegateway and creates a preview popup when hovering. However, the font is very unreadable and so I have tried to change it to black.

The popup currently has a near-white font (that blends with the popup) 
and needs to have a black font, with the rest of the page content needs the near white font. When the script runs through it generates a div surrounding each bible verse, and the js applies to it (the div in which the Bible verse text appears is in the `bg_popup-content-bible` with a `<p>` tag), making it popup like so.

I have noted that in the script there is a section that calls for a "addedCSS"

```
var addCSS = function() {
    if (!addedCSS) {
        var css = document.createElement('link');
        css.type = "text/css";
        css.rel = "stylesheet";
        if (browser.search('MSIE 6.0') != -1) {
            browser = 'ie6';
            css.href = cdHost + '/theme/bglinks-ie.css';
        } else {
            css.href = cdHost + '/theme/popover.css';
        }
        css.media = "screen";
        var n1 = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].childNodes[0]
        n1.parentNode.insertBefore(css, n1);
        addedCSS = true;
    }
}
```

I do not believe it is possible to change the url that the addedCss pull from, from the MediaWiki:Common.css, as this script was not made for the specific system being used (when removing or altering the variable the script does not work). I don't know if this is not happening because of a javascript issue (which is beyond me, and it's difficult to alter the script without breaking it) or if it's just a matter of incorrect css, but I have been working on this for several months here and there, and would like to get this final detail to work.

Comment: Do you have a link to the site with the script running?

Comment: @tw16 http://churchofcwa.wikia.com is the site in which it will run

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to

```
  .bg_popup-content-bible {color:#000000 !important;}
```

Comment: Didn't work. Thanks for the try though, any other ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the CSS specificity checker. I have tested the below css on your site and it works. Make sure to put it in your *site.css*.

```
.bg_popup-content-bible p {
    color: #000000;
}
```

It needs to be written as above because it has to override the `<p>` styling you've already set earlier in *site.css*:

```
p {
    color: #f5f5f5
}
```

**EDIT**

It is not a problem with the script. Based on what you have said in the comments it seems like you are unable to actually edit / output css. So the other option is just to modify the script you've posted above:

Change this:

```
tooltip.innerHTML = '<div class="bg_popup-header"><div class="bg_popup-header_title"><strong>'+reference_display+' '+tooltip_content.version+'</strong></div></div><div class="bg_popup-content"><div class="bg_popup-content-bible"><p>'+tooltip_content.text+' <a class="bg_popup-copyright" href="'+bgHost+tooltip_content.version_url+'" target="_blank">('+tooltip_content.version+')</a> <a class="bg_popup-more" href="'+bgHost+'/passage/?search='+tooltip_content.reference+'&version='+tooltip_content.version+'&src=tools" target="_blank">More</a></p></div></div><div class="bg_popup-footer"><a class="bg_popup-bglogo" href="'+bgHost+'/" target="_blank"></a></div>';
```

to this:

```
tooltip.innerHTML = '<div class="bg_popup-header"><div class="bg_popup-header_title"><strong>'+reference_display+' '+tooltip_content.version+'</strong></div></div><div class="bg_popup-content"><div class="bg_popup-content-bible"><p style="color:#000000">'+tooltip_content.text+' <a class="bg_popup-copyright" href="'+bgHost+tooltip_content.version_url+'" target="_blank">('+tooltip_content.version+')</a> <a class="bg_popup-more" href="'+bgHost+'/passage/?search='+tooltip_content.reference+'&version='+tooltip_content.version+'&src=tools" target="_blank">More</a></p></div></div><div class="bg_popup-footer"><a class="bg_popup-bglogo" href="'+bgHost+'/" target="_blank"></a></div>';
```

Given the way Stack formats the code above, to make it very clear you are editing the part of the line above that says:

```
<p>'+tooltip_content.text+'
```

and making it:

```
<p style="color:#000000">'+tooltip_content.text+'
```

Comment: The problem is, adding it in a site.css will not work. I added it Common.CSS, but do not have access to raw css (with how the system works it has to be under the MediaWiki namespace). Would it work if I created MediaWiki:Site.css. The CSS pages aren't raw, but the system treats them as they are. I tried a popular script that has the same function from a different provider and it did not work. Hopefully this one will

Comment: @Superdadsuper: I'm not quite sure what you are saying. Are you saying you don't have access to css files and that you're adding css through a cms? Ultimately it shouldn't matter though. As long as you can output css the selector `.bg_popup-content-bible p` will work as it has a higher specificity than the default `p` styling I mentioned in my answer. If it is not working then it suggests to me that you are not actually outputting css. After you've added the css to MediaWiki:Common.css make sure to do a hard refresh or clear your cache before checking to see if it has worked.

Comment: I tried your change you suggested in the coments, and added to MediaWiki:Common.css, through the CMS. It still does not work, which is very odd these scripts do not work

Comment: Sorry I haven't replied for a few days. I have the script uploaded, but the hosting company requires manual review of all javascript changes before publishing due to a major security issue that occured a few months. I uploaded this changes today and will get back to you after its approved and i test it –

Comment: When I altered the script, the entire script breaks. i notice even the slightest change to the script somehow breaks the entire thing.

Comment: @Superdadsuper: I'm sorry, there is nothing else I can suggest. If you can't output css and you can't edit js then you're not going to be able to change the font colour. There is no reason why changing `<p>` to `<p style="color:#000000">` would break the script. Maybe you need to get support from wikia or the people who made your theme to be able to work out where to make the css change so that it will be appear in the source code.

Comment: Originally I tried another script, I have gotten support from the person who made the this and the script I tried using before, and they did not work. Unfortunately both Biblegateway (the maker of the script I want to use) and Logos Bible Software (maker of the more common alternative to the script I am using) no longer supports it and on contacting Wikia said I needed to contact them. I will try sending Wikia an email again to see if I can get help. I appreciate, nevertheless your attempts on trying to help me with my script and that is something that is very helpful to our ministry